Usage cutoff for unpublished Client IDs - how does this affect ClientIDs created with AppRegNew.aspx?
I have been aware of the scheduled retirement of SharePoint Add-ins, but two days ago, I received an alert from Microsoft indicating that any unpublished Client IDs would stop working on May 1, 2025.
To the best of my knowledge, this is the first I'm hearing about this May 1 cutoff.
The relevant part of that alert:

Our records indicate that your company is using client IDs in unpublished SharePoint Add-ins. Use of client IDs for unpublished offers is not recommended, and support for these client IDs will be unavailable starting on November 15, 2024.
To keep your current client IDs functional after November 15, 2024, until May 1, 2025, ensure you have a Microsoft Entra ID associated with your Partner Center account. Without this association, you won't be able to renew your client IDs, preventing authentication for current applications that may have been deployed on-premises.
Required action
Associate a Microsoft Entra ID with your Partner Center account before November 15, 2024.
Before May 1, 2025, update your application to have no dependencies on client IDs associated with unpublished Add-ins:

It's clear enough to me that any unpublished Client IDs in the Partner Center will stop working on May 1, but what's not clear to me is what this means for Add-Ins whose Client IDs were created/registered using AppRegNew.aspx and not the Partner Center. I have customers with their own deployments of my Add-In and they used AppRegNew.aspx to generate their Client IDs and Client Secrets.
Is there any announcement from Microsoft regarding that matter?
